# How to make an erd with 'spesific' requirements?

Tags: data-modeling, erd

im a new student of computer science and i got this database modelling course,
on my last course my lecturer explain me about basic erd modelling such as relation,entities,chen and crowsfoot notation

and i got a task that tell me to make an erd about train booking with some spesific requirements, here's the requirement
[requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AbW3.png)

and here's what i've made from what i know from my last course
[my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19UfY.png)

im stuck about the requirements, im very glad if someone can help/explain me about how to make an erd with that requirements, Thanks

Comment: Do not add the assignment as an image, add it to your question directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.